# TightVNC server not listening for connections

Tags: windows-xp, vnc, vncserver, tightvnc

When I start TightVNC in Windows and I put the mouse over the taskbar icon it says that TightVNC server is not listening for connections.

Edit: It started listening to connection again, and is working fine. I don't know what happened before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out what the reason was. It:s because TightVNC server was already running as a service. Its icon doesn't show until a connection is made. If you try to run the TightVNC server program while the service is already running then thats what happens.

Comment: Reason for this can also be that something else is using vnc server port (default 5900).  It usually is another instance of vnc server.  As a temporary measure, you can set the port to 5901 in the vnc server preferences.  Then you'll have to type hostname:1 (or hostanem::5901) into your client.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same probleme (thightVNC service not listening), so I put 5901 on "deskA computer and 5902 on the other one( DeskB). Then from my desk if I want to be connected, I search for deskA:1 and for the other one deskb:2

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason my server wasnt listening was because realvnc was installed but didnt have a taskbar icon so tightvnc got installed too.

removed realvnc and left tightvnc running

Answer (score 1):

It definitely means something else in using the port. Change it to 5801, 5901, etc. and the server will start listening.